# Issues with running my Apache Solr project:

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, solr, google-code

I'm trying to set up `Apache Solr` and run some experiments. I've set up the Solr search engine on my Ubuntu 18.04, indexed a few files, and it works perfectly given a specific query. The admin page is accessible on the default port on `localhost:8983/solr`

Now I was trying to setup a web-based client communicating with Solr. I found this simple project located at Google Code **[here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/solr-search-html/)**. I extracted it, and follow the simple instructions to make the contents available via localhost http (using `python -m http.server`). So when I go to `http://localhost:8000`, I see the `index.html` client. Apparently the only thing we need to check for integration is `js/solr-search.js` file to make sure the `solrURL` is set correctly, which the default is good already:

```
var solrUrl = 'http://' + document.location.hostname + ':8983/solr/';
```

But when I try to press the `search` button, it doesn't show any results and the loading icon keeps showing:

[image: Apache solr html client]

Where is the problem? How can I fix the issue?

**UPDATE: I debugged and noticed this error on `index.html`:**

`Failed to load http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?wt=json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console? Do you see a request being made in the network activity of your browser? If so, what is the status?

Comment: No. The server echo's all http request. Looks like the search button when clicked doesn't send any request.

Comment: @SteveVaughan `Failed to load http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?wt=json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Which is caused by your HTML files being located on a different port than what Solr lives on. For that to work they have to be served by the same httpd / host

Comment: I installed a plugin for that to work. But need a permanent and in-code solution.

Comment: In order to avoid this, you will have to setup some sort of API that runs on the same port as your web server that delivers the html page. That API should be the one that calls solr. There are a lot of options you could go with for this, but there may be a way to use the python http server and provide a proxy to your solr api.